# SFTP prompting for password even though password is in script

Tags: sftp

I am trying to transfer a file from one server to a remote server using SFTP. Client is not ready for key setup so 
I have gone through other questions on this forum related to SFTP and tried all. But still its not working in my case.

My Script :-

```
#!/bin/sh
# sample automatic ftp script to dump a file
USER="username"
PASSWORD="password"
HOST="hostname"
sftp $USER@$HOST << EOF
$PASSOWRD
cd test_path
put test_file.txt
quit
EOF
```

Comment: Did this script work after correcting the misprint? (as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16372446/5361779 answer)

Answer (score 9):

You have a misprint in your script - you are writing $PASSOWRD instead of $PASSWORD, so it substitutes empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `expect`. It's very easy and simple;

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
spawn sftp <userid>@<server> 
expect "password:" 
send "<password>\n" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "cd <remot dirctory>\r" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "mput * \r" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "quit \r"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below steps,

```
lftp -u $user,$passwd sftp://$host << --EOF--
cd $directory
put $srcfile
quit
--EOF--
```